# Why is FullCalendar event parsing limited to Location and Description when using the extendedProps in the event object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have several extendedProperties for my Google Events. I'm able to retrieve those values in php to verify they exist as part of the event.

The FullCal docs at [events from Google Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/google-calendar)
states:

> *Extended Properties...
> Google Calendar’s API allows you to specify Extended Properties for your events. The extended properties will be available in the extendedProps hash of each Event Object.*

When the FullCal object is viewed in the console only "Location" and "Description" are shown.
The Google event object is massive with many other properties available at the same level as location and description (start, end, organizer and more)..so why aren't most of them in the FullCal event object?

My FullCal event render has:

```
info.event.extendedProps.location;  //returns the location                          
info.event.extendedProps.extendedProperties; //returns undefined
```

Here is a list of all the properties Google events offer: [Google
Calendar API
Event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)

specifically I want access to "extendedProperties"(same level as location)

I know the solution must be simple, FullCal is comprehensive but I can't figure this out.

Here is my returned google event object in the php API format :

```
2nd Test params (2020-08-08T09:00:00-05:00)
Google_Service_Calendar_Event Object
(
[collection_key:protected] => recurrence
[anyoneCanAddSelf] => 
[attachmentsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttachment
[attachmentsDataType:protected] => array
[attendeesType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee
[attendeesDataType:protected] => array
[attendeesOmitted] => 
[colorId] => 
[conferenceDataType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData
[conferenceDataDataType:protected] => 
[created] => 2020-07-29T15:19:20.000Z
[creatorType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventCreator
[creatorDataType:protected] => 
[description] => somestuff   /*================DESCRIPTION==========================*/
[endType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime
[endDataType:protected] => 
[endTimeUnspecified] => 
[etag] => /* ETag of the resource */
[extendedPropertiesType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventExtendedProperties
[extendedPropertiesDataType:protected] => 
[gadgetType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventGadget
[gadgetDataType:protected] => 
[guestsCanInviteOthers] => 
[guestsCanModify] => 
[guestsCanSeeOtherGuests] => 
[hangoutLink] => 
[htmlLink] => https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid= /* your event id */
[iCalUID] =>  /* see google event doc  link */
[id] => /* your cal id  */
[kind] => calendar#event
[location] => somewhere /*================LOCATION==========================*/
[locked] => 
[organizerType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventOrganizer
[organizerDataType:protected] => 
[originalStartTimeType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime
[originalStartTimeDataType:protected] => 
[privateCopy] => 
[recurrence] => 
[recurringEventId] => 
[remindersType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminders
[remindersDataType:protected] => 
[sequence] => 1
[sourceType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventSource
[sourceDataType:protected] => 
[startType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime
[startDataType:protected] => 
[status] => confirmed
[summary] => 2nd Test params
[transparency] => 
[updated] => 2020-08-05T04:07:41.552Z
[visibility] => 
[internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[modelData:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[creator] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventCreator Object
    (
        [displayName] => 
        [email] => someone@gmail.com
        [id] => 
        [self] => 
        [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [processed:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[organizer] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventOrganizer Object
    (
        [displayName] => Coastal Kitchen & Bath
        [email] => /* yourcal info */ .calendar.google.com
        [id] => 
        [self] => 1
        [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [processed:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[start] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 
        [dateTime] => 2020-08-08T09:00:00-05:00
        [timeZone] => America/Chicago
        [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [processed:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[end] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 
        [dateTime] => 2020-08-08T09:00:00-05:00
        [timeZone] => America/Chicago
        [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [processed:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )
                     /*================EXTENDED PROPERTIES==========================*/
[extendedProperties] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventExtendedProperties Object
    (
        [private] => Array
            (
                [patsAllowed] => yes
            )

        [shared] => 
        [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [processed:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[reminders] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminders Object
    (
        [collection_key:protected] => overrides
        [overridesType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminder
        [overridesDataType:protected] => array
        [useDefault] => 1
        [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [processed:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```